# Actionlistener in the command of the side menu opens blank form but the same in the button action listener opens the form normally

Tags: codenameone

I have called a form name Groups from button action listener and command action listener. In both, I have called a connection request. In postResponse method of 
the connection showForm is declared. The issue here is that it works great when I click the button and the groups  form opens normally but when I click the command from the hamburger menu, the blank form is shown but as soon as the screen is touched, the contents are displayed (both in real devices and simulator). PS I have also called revalidate method in Groups form. How can it work in one and not in other because I have same code in both command & button actionListener

Command in the side menu

```
Command goToGroup = new Command("Tables",homeIcon1) {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        connectionGroup = new GroupConnection();
        connectionGroup.groupConnection(StateMachine.this);
    }

};
f.addCommand(goToGroup);
```

button action listener in a form

```
groups.addActionListener((e) -> {
    connectionGroup = new GroupConnection();
    connectionGroup.groupConnection(this);
});
```

Connection

```
public class GroupConnection {

void groupConnection(StateMachine sm) {

    ConnectionRequest connectionRequest = new ConnectionRequest() {
        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
         - - - - - - 
         - - - - - -
        }
        @Override
        protected void postResponse() {
            sm.showForm("Groups", null);
        }
        - - - - - - 
        - - - - - -
    };
  }
}
```

groups form:

```
protected void beforeGroups(Form f) {
    Display.getInstance().scheduleBackgroundTask(() -> {
        Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
            if (connectionGroup.responses != null) {
                for (Map<String, Object> element : connectionGroup.responses) {
                    String id = (String) element.get("id");
                    String tableName = (String) element.get("name");
                    String tableImg = (String) element.get("tablelogo");
                    - - - - - -  - -
                    - - - -- - - - - -
                }
            }
         });
        f.revalidate();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between the two is that the side menu navigates to a temporary form and then reshows the form after. I'm guessing your call to `revalidate()` was made at the wrong time when the form hasn't been shown/constructed yet.

Comment: sorry i missed a point, I have used scheduleBackgroundTask in the groups form (plz see above in the question). Is it the problem? I've kept it since i want to add toolbar search. And in the blog scheduleBackgroundTask is also used. I jst followed the blog. I jst wonder why same code in btn action listener works but not in command action listener

Comment: I don't see the need for the schedule background task. It looks to me like you are relying on a race condition instead of doing the revalidate when you know all the data is in place.